# Addressing Precision Challenges in Floating-Point Sequence Management

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, sequence

I am facing an issue related to organizing the sequence values in **SQL Server** and would appreciate some guidance on finding the best approach to address it. Here's the problem:

We are using **float** data type in SQL Server to determine the values of a sequence. When we change the order of folders or documents within this sequence, we use a formula to calculate the new sequence value for the moved folder or document in between two others. The formula we are using is as follows:

**New Sequence Value = (Value of Previous Sequence + Value of Next Sequence) / 2**

So, if you are moving a folder between two folders with sequence values 1 and 2, your new sequence value would be:

```
                 (1 + 2) / 2 = 1.5

                 (1.5 +2) / 2 = 1.75
                 (1.75 + 2) / 2 = 1.875 ...
```

However, we have encountered an issue with this formula. After moving items around approximately 14 times, the fractional part of the float number starts getting filled up, causing inaccuracies in the sequence values.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to address this problem and find a more robust way to organize the sequence values without running into the precision issues associated with the float data type. Any insights or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use float, use int, and reorder all the items rather than reducing the number continually.

Comment: use numeric with the precision you want to use

Comment: Are you doing some sort of tree structure?

Comment: @siggemannen more like a linked list. We need to change the sequence of item(s) when moving from one place to another at the same level, for example within the same folder.

Comment: does numeric(19,12) or something like that work for you?

Comment: @DaleK this can affect performance if we are working with millions of items

Comment: This is not a floating-point issue. No fixed-width type, whether floating-point or integer or non-numeric, can accommodate a growing need for more bits. Every time you put a sequence between two other sequences, you need one more bit than the parent sequences needed. You either need another method of identifying the sequences (including possibly changing/resetting the identifiers at times) or a variable-length type, such as a growing string.

Comment: Edit the question to explain the requirements of these sequence values. What do you need them for? Can they be all reset to new values at times? Can you use strings for them?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a process to spread out the values to create room.  It's fine if they start to accumulate lots of digits of precision, so long as there's enough room.

So periodically rewrite the sequence using a query like setting all the values to whole numbers with ROW_NUMBER().

You can also trigger this when you discover that a new sequence value is equal to one of the ones you're trying to find a value between.

Comment: Doubling all the values will have no effect on the precision issue as floating-point precision is relative to the significand, not the exponent.

Comment: Right, because floats become less dense as they become bigger.